# Unable to change between switch states in my code when running (ATMEGA328p)

Tags: c, arduino-uno

When running code, it supposed to be in standby until pushbutton is pressed which brings it to the next state which is running where all my digital outputs (LEDs) function.  However as soon as I upload the code to the ATMEGA328p and starts in running mode and wont change.  The pushbutton is connected to the pin on the Arduino that has a small LED inbedded into the board, so i know it is definitely switching.

Any help would be appreciated, I am having the same issue with another code, so I know it is something I am definitely doing wrong.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define SET_BIT(reg, pin)           (reg) |= (1 << (pin))
#define CLEAR_BIT(reg, pin)       (reg) &= ~(1 << (pin))
#define WRITE_BIT(reg, pin, value)   (reg) = (((reg) & ~(1 << (pin))) | ((value) << (pin)))
#define BIT_VALUE(reg, pin)       (((reg) >> (pin)) & 1)
#define BIT_IS_SET(reg, pin)         (BIT_VALUE((reg),(pin))==1)

//uart definitions
#define BAUD (9600)
#define MYUBRR (F_CPU/16/BAUD-1)

// These buffers may be any size from 2 to 256 bytes.
#define  RX_BUFFER_SIZE  64
#define  TX_BUFFER_SIZE  64


//uart definitions
unsigned char rx_buf;

static volatile uint8_t tx_buffer[TX_BUFFER_SIZE];
static volatile uint8_t tx_buffer_head;
static volatile uint8_t tx_buffer_tail;
static volatile uint8_t rx_buffer[RX_BUFFER_SIZE];
static volatile uint8_t rx_buffer_head;
static volatile uint8_t rx_buffer_tail;


// Functions declaration
void setup(void);
void process(void);
void uart_init(unsigned int ubrr);
void valve_pot_init(void);

// Uart functions
void uart_putchar(uint8_t c);
uint8_t uart_getchar(void);
uint8_t uart_available(void);
void uart_putstring(unsigned char* s);
void uart_getLine(unsigned char* buf, uint8_t n);

// ADC functions
uint16_t adc_read(uint8_t channel);
void adc_init();

// Global Variables & Defines for Puush Button Debouncing
#define PButton 0b00010000 // Location of pushbutton input in Port B
volatile uint8_t pushbuttons_db = 0;
volatile uint8_t reg1;
volatile uint8_t reg2;

// Setting up switch statement within process function
enum {
    standby,
    running,
    };
    
void digital_io_init( void ){
    
    // LED Setup    
    SET_BIT(DDRB,PB0); // Red LED, valve is operational, Unsafe to touch
    SET_BIT(DDRB,PB1); // Green LED, valve is non-operational, Safe to touch
    SET_BIT(DDRB,PB2); // Red LED, valve is fully open
    SET_BIT(DDRB,PB3); // Green LED, valve is fully closed
    SET_BIT(DDRD,PD2); // Back Light LED
    
    // Push Button Setup
    CLEAR_BIT(DDRB,PB4);
    
}

void debounce_init(void) {
    cli();
    
    // Setting Clear Time Compare on Timer0
    SET_BIT(TCCR0A,WGM01);
    CLEAR_BIT(TCCR0A,WGM00);
    
    // Setting Prescalar of 256 on Timer0
    SET_BIT(TCCR0B,CS02);
    CLEAR_BIT(TCCR0B,CS01);
    CLEAR_BIT(TCCR0B,CS00);
    
    // Setting 2ms period on Timer0
    CLEAR_BIT(OCR0A,7);
    SET_BIT(OCR0A,6);
    SET_BIT(OCR0A,5);
    SET_BIT(OCR0A,4);
    SET_BIT(OCR0A,3);
    SET_BIT(OCR0A,2);
    CLEAR_BIT(OCR0A,1);
    SET_BIT(OCR0A,0);
    
    // Enabling Interupt on Output Compare Match A 
    CLEAR_BIT(TIMSK0,OCIE0B);
    SET_BIT(TIMSK0,OCIE0A);
    CLEAR_BIT(TIMSK0,TOIE0);

    sei();
}

//main loop
int main() {
    
    // Digital I/O initialise
    digital_io_init();
    
    // Pot for valve, ADC initialise
    valve_pot_init();
    
    // Push button & debouncing initialise
    debounce_init();

    for ( ;; ) {
        process();
        // _delay_ms(1);
    }
}

//initialises ADC and UART port
void valve_pot_init(void) {

    //init uart
    uart_init(MYUBRR);

    // Initialise adc
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,ADEN);
    
    // ADC Enable and pre-scaler of 128: ref table 24-5 in datasheet
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,ADPS2);
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,ADPS1);
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,ADPS0);
    // ADCSRA = (1 << ADEN) | (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0);

   // Selecting channel and ref input voltage
    SET_BIT(ADMUX,REFS0);
    CLEAR_BIT(ADMUX,MUX0);
    CLEAR_BIT(ADMUX,MUX1);
    CLEAR_BIT(ADMUX,MUX2);
    CLEAR_BIT(ADMUX,MUX3);
    CLEAR_BIT(ADMUX,REFS1);

}


void process(void) {

    // For Push Button & Debouncing
    uint8_t pb_now = 0;
    uint8_t pb_prev = 0;
    uint8_t pb_pressed;
    
    // Determining whether push button has been pressed
    pb_now = pushbuttons_db;
    pb_pressed = pb_now & (pb_now ^ pb_prev);
    pb_prev = pb_now;

    char temp_buf[64];

   // Start single conversion by setting ADSC bit in ADCSRA
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);

    // Wait for ADSC bit to clear, signalling conversion complete.
     while ( ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC) ) {}

    // Result now available in ADC
    uint16_t pot = ADC;
    uint16_t valve_position = pot / 10.23; // This will give an output range of 0 to 100%
    
    // convert uint16_t to string
    itoa(valve_position, (char *)temp_buf,10);
    
    // Send serial data
   uart_putstring((unsigned char *) temp_buf);
   uart_putchar('\t');

    static uint8_t state = standby ;
        
        switch (state){
            
            // This state is for no one is in the sauna, system on standby
            case standby:   // Clearing Light Outputs
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTB,PB0); // Red LED, valve is operational, Unsafe to touch
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTB,PB1); // Green LED, valve is non-operational, Safe to touch
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTB,PB2); // Red LED, valve is fully open
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTB,PB3); // Green LED, valve is fully closed
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTD,PD2); // Back Light LED
                    
                            // Turning On Green LED on to say sauna is safe
                            SET_BIT(PORTB,1); // Green LED, valve is non-operational, Safe to touch
                    
                            // Button pressed means someone has entered sauna, go to running state
                            if ( pb_pressed & PButton ) {
                                state = running;
                            }
            
            // This state is for when someone is using the sauna, system is on
            case running:   // Cleaing Light Outputs
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTB,PB0); // Red LED, valve is operational, Unsafe to touch
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTB,PB1); // Green LED, valve is non-operational, Safe to touch
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTB,PB2); // Red LED, valve is fully open
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTB,PB3); // Green LED, valve is fully closed
                            CLEAR_BIT(PORTD,PD2); // Back Light LED
                    
                            // Turning On Red LED & LCD Back Light
                            SET_BIT(PORTD,PD2); // Back Light LED, turn on
                            SET_BIT(PORTB,PB0); // Red LED, valve is operational, Unsafe to touch
                            
                            // Physical indication of valve being fully open
                            if ( valve_position == 100 ){
                                SET_BIT(PORTB,2); // Red LED, valve is fully open
                            }
                            
                            // Physical indication of valve being fully closed
                            if ( valve_position == 0 ){
                                SET_BIT(PORTB,3); // Green LED, valve is fully closed
                            }
                            
                            // Button pressed means someone is going into sauna, go to next state
                            if ( pb_pressed & PButton ){
                                state = standby;
                            }
                            
            default: state = standby;
        } // Switch Statement
}




//PLEASE NOTE THIS VERSION OF UART USES INTERRUPTS

/*  ****** serial uart definitions ************ */
/******************  interrupt based  ********/

// Initialize the UART
void uart_init(unsigned int ubrr) {

    cli();

    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)(ubrr);
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
    tx_buffer_head = tx_buffer_tail = 0;
    rx_buffer_head = rx_buffer_tail = 0;

    sei();

}



// Transmit a byte
void uart_putchar(uint8_t c) {
    uint8_t i;

    i = tx_buffer_head + 1;
    if ( i >= TX_BUFFER_SIZE ) i = 0;
    while ( tx_buffer_tail == i ); // wait until space in buffer
    //cli();
    tx_buffer[i] = c;
    tx_buffer_head = i;
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0) | (1 << UDRIE0);
    //sei();
}

// Receive a byte
uint8_t uart_getchar(void) {
    uint8_t c, i;

    while ( rx_buffer_head == rx_buffer_tail ); // wait for character
    i = rx_buffer_tail + 1;
    if ( i >= RX_BUFFER_SIZE ) i = 0;
    c = rx_buffer[i];
    rx_buffer_tail = i;
    return c;
}


// Transmit a string
void uart_putstring(unsigned char* s)
{
    // transmit character until NULL is reached
    while(*s > 0) uart_putchar(*s++);
}


// Receive a string
void uart_getLine(unsigned char* buf, uint8_t n)
{
    uint8_t bufIdx = 0;
    unsigned char c;

    // while received character is not carriage return
    // and end of buffer has not been reached
    do
    {
        // receive character
        c = uart_getchar();

        // store character in buffer
        buf[bufIdx++] = c;
    }
    while((bufIdx < n) && (c != '\n'));

    // ensure buffer is null terminated
    buf[bufIdx] = 0;
}



uint8_t uart_available(void) {
    uint8_t head, tail;

    head = rx_buffer_head;
    tail = rx_buffer_tail;
    if ( head >= tail ) return head - tail;
    return RX_BUFFER_SIZE + head - tail;
}


// Transmit Interrupt
ISR(USART_UDRE_vect) {
    uint8_t i;

    if ( tx_buffer_head == tx_buffer_tail ) {
        // buffer is empty, disable transmit interrupt
        UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);
    }
    else {
        i = tx_buffer_tail + 1;
        if ( i >= TX_BUFFER_SIZE ) i = 0;
        UDR0 = tx_buffer[i];
        tx_buffer_tail = i;
    }
}

// Receive Interrupt
ISR(USART_RX_vect) {
    uint8_t c, i;

    c = UDR0;
    i = rx_buffer_head + 1;
    if ( i >= RX_BUFFER_SIZE ) i = 0;
    if ( i != rx_buffer_tail ) {
        rx_buffer[i] = c;
        rx_buffer_head = i;
    }
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){

    uint8_t pb0;
    uint8_t delta;

    pb0 = ~PINB;
    
    delta = pb0 ^ pushbuttons_db;

    pushbuttons_db ^= (reg2 & delta);

    reg2 = (reg1 & delta);
    reg1 = delta;

}
```

Comment: Hint: `break` or you get fall-through.

Comment: @tadman I did have breaks in there as before hand, not operating in either scenario, is there anything else I could try?

Comment: They're kind of super important or you're having all the code in there run sequentially under certain conditions. You need to fix that. Removing them is not a good plan.

Comment: You probably want that delay back in, too, or you lock up your CPU running that loop.

Comment: I don't know man, this code is pretty broken. For instance you aren't calling setup() and you aren't calling adc_init() .. Have you tried setting a break point just before the switch, check that the registers/variables are what you expect them to be.
Otherwise, comment out all non critical code, i.e. evaluate only the push button. Try to give the state some dummy value and see what happens.